# Query MySQL funciona no Workbench, mas não no script php

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz uma busca sobre esse problema, encontrei vários com situação similar e, no entanto, os problemas eram outros. Tenho o seguinte código onde a query, se for executada na console, MySQL Workbench ou phpmyadmin funciona perfeitamente.No caso, verifiquei a conexão com o banco e está tudo certo, pois de modifico a query para uma outra bem simples, o script funciona corretamente e traz o resultado esperado. Mas, com essa query, o browser não retorna nada, só uma página em branco. OBS: as mensagens de erro estão habilitadas no php.ini. Obrigado!

```
<?php
require_once "conn.php";

$dbconnecta = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
if(!$dbconnecta) {
  die("Not connected: ". mysqli_error());
}else{
    mysqli_select_db($dbconnecta, $dba);
}

$query = "SELECT
n.nid,
a.field_dc_autores_nid,
n.title as titulo,
s.title as autor,
filename,
field_dublincore_source_value,
field_ano_da_publica_o_value,
art.name,
ed.name
FROM
node n
INNER JOIN
field_data_field_dc_autores a
ON a.entity_id = n.nid
AND n.type = 'conteudo'
INNER JOIN node s
ON a.field_dc_autores_nid = s.nid
AND s.type = 'autor'
INNER JOIN field_data_field_arquivo ar
ON ar.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN file_managed
ON fid = field_arquivo_fid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_dublincore_source f
ON f.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN ensp_producaocientifica.field_data_field_ano_da_publica_o ano
ON ano.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN ensp_producaocientifica.field_data_field_grupo_da_producao_bibli
ON field_data_field_grupo_da_producao_bibli.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data art
ON tid = field_grupo_da_producao_bibli_tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_dublincore_publisher pub
ON pub.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data ed
ON ed.tid = field_dublincore_publisher_tid
WHERE n.type = 'conteudo'
AND art.name like 'Artigos completos publicados em periódicos'
AND n.status = 1
AND n.nid = 369751
ORDER BY
nid DESC,
a.delta ASC
";
$dbresult = mysqli_query($dbconnecta, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbresult)) {
  echo $row['titulo'] . "<br>";
 echo $row['field_ano_da_publica_o_value'];
}
```

Comment: Adicione no inicio do script: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(A_LL);`

Comment: Algumas linguagens não interpretam a quebra linha. Pode adicionar ""+"" para cada quebra de linha: `$query = "SELECT
n.nid,"
+"a.field_dc_autores_nid,"
+"n.title as titulo,"
+"s.title as autor,"....`

Comment: Grande chance de ser o acento em "periódicos", e seu fonte não ter sido salvo no mesmo encoding do DB. A propósito, usar like dessa forma aí não faz sentido. Além disso, seu código não está exibindo erros de SQL aparentemente.

Comment: Gente, obrigado por responderem. Bom, vamos lá: Coloquei a parte de:

Comment: Meu comentário anterior foi cortado. Ainda aprendendo como lidar com esse sistema....
Gente, obrigado por responderem. Bom, vamos lá: @rray , Coloquei a parte de: `init_set('display_erros', true)`, etc e o `error_reporting`, mas não retornou nada. A página não retornou nada, tendo ficado tudo em branco.
@EmanuelF , Adicionar + para cada quebra de linha. Até experimentei colocar a query numa só linha, mas o resultado não se alterou.
@Bacco , modifiquei a query para tirar o acento, de forma a ficar `"Artigos completos publicados em%"` e o resultado também não se alterou...